# Travis CI for Android - Build Error: Failed to find target & Could not find dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

I am trying to set up Travis CI for my [existing Android project.](https://github.com/evercam/evercam-play-android) I've added the .travis.yml:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-21.1.2
    - android-22
    - extra-google-google_play_services
```

But it always fails in Travis CI with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':evercamPlay'.
failed to find target android-22 : /usr/local/android-sdk
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 16.801 secs
The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

What should I do to get rid of this error?

---

Update:
After updating build tools to version 22.0.1, this error is gone but got new error:

```
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
...
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0.
...
```

In my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your updated question is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644996/travis-ci-android-cant-find-version-that-matches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update the build tools to the version 22.X, I have tried in my project configuration and that works.

```
android:
  components:
    - android-22
    - build-tools-22.0.1
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks! But then I got new error:Could not find Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add - extra-android-support

Comment: Tried that but got no luck.. Seems extra-android-support is already included by default. Which support library version are you using in your project?

Comment: @Liuting I have submited a pull request to fix it, please merge(https://github.com/evercam/evercam-play-android/pull/36)

Comment: add -extra-android-m2repository and -extra-google-m2repository for gradle.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible that Travis hasn't been updated with the appropriate sdks yet. From [their docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/) (as of June 9, 2015):

> Pre-installed components #
>
> While the following components are preinstalled, the exact list may change without prior notice. To ensure the stability of your build environment, we recommend that you explicitly specify the required components for your project.
>
> - platform-tools
> - build-tools-21.1.1
> - android-21
> - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-21
> - android-20
> - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-wear-20
> - android-19
> - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19
> - android-18
> - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-18
> - android-17
> - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-17
> - android-16
> - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-16
> - android-15
> - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-15
> - android-10
> - extra-android-support
> - extra-google-google_play_services
> - extra-google-m2repository
> - extra-android-m2repository

No mention of v22 sdk or build tools there.

Comment: They dont mention it but is supported.

Comment: Does this mean we cannot use android-22??

Comment: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-environment-updates/2015-04-09/#Android-VM - https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/blob/master/ci_environment/android-sdk/attributes/default.rb

Comment: Igor, last update seems that was cancelled but you can update tools adding platform-tool and tool to components, see my response below

Answer (score 1):

```
language: android
    android:
      components:
        - platform-tool
        - tool
        - android-22
        - build-tools-22.0.1
        - extra-android-m2repository
        - extra-google-m2repository
```