# How to run Travis-Ci with android 22

Tags: android, travis-ci

With some open-source projects, I use travis-ci to perform my continuous integration, and I really like this website.

There's my problem, when I set my android sdk to  'android-22', the build fail

```
Build tools 22.0.0 missing. Downloading...
Compilation API android-22 missing. Downloading...
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find target android-22 : /usr/local/android-sdk
```

Travis works fine with android-19, following the [official documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/)

How can I make it works ?

https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

My travis file is

```
    language: android

    jdk:
      - openjdk7

    android:
      components:

        - build-tools-21.1.1
        - android-21
        - extra-android-support
        - extra-google-google_play_services
        - extra-google-m2repository
        - extra-android-m2repository

    notifications:
      email: true

    # Turn off caching to avoid any caching problems
    cache: false
    # Use the Travis Container-Based Infrastructure (see #203)
    sudo: false

    install:
      # Ensure Gradle wrapper is executable, download wrapper and show version
      - chmod +x ./gradlew; ls -l gradlew; ./gradlew wrapper -v
      # Download and show android dependencies
      # - ./gradlew androidDependencies

    script:
      - ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Comment: Share your travis.yml content here to fix it or read http://stackoverflow.com/a/30730087/1009132

Comment: https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

Comment: I added the travis file

Comment: I tested my response to be sure that works forking your project

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find Build Tools revision 22.0.0](https://travis-ci.org/florent37/MaterialViewPager/builds/74908439#L1342)

You need to match the installed build tools version and the project required version.

**Solution**

Change your build.gradle file to use the stable build tools version [here](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager/blob/master/build.gradle#L26).

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION='22.0.0'
```

by

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION='22.0.1'
```

**Demonstration**

I forked your project and solved the issue [here](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/MaterialViewPager/builds)

**Note**

I know that your latest commits are working without do it but you are downloading the build tools 22.0.1, after that trying to use version 22.0.0, missing it and downloading it [here](https://travis-ci.org/florent37/MaterialViewPager/builds/80088340#L1342).

> Build tools 22.0.0 missing. Downloading...

It's not clean and you are using an obsolete version without bug fixes.